# Stuck on IE7 accordion behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

Hello Guys I'm new to jQuery.
as you can see this accordion is working on FF and chrome but giving issues on IE7
http://brisbanebox.com/demo/multi_level_menu_accordion/1.html

Click on 222 > > then on 999..it collapse to 222 on IE7

on ff it still remain open

Any help would be appreciated

Here is my JS code

```
$(function(){
    $('.toc_content').find('li').each(function(){
        var li=$(this);
        if(li.find('> ul').length==1){
            li.addClass('collapsed').find('> a').click(function(e){

                var li=$(this).parent('li'), ul=li.find('> ul');

                ul.toggle();
                if(ul.is(':hidden')){
                    li.removeClass('collapsed').addClass('opened');
                }
                else{
                    li.removeClass('opened').addClass('collapsed')
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
var element = new Array();

$(function(){
    lastName = window.location.pathname.split("/");
    currentWindowLocation =  lastName[lastName.length-1];
    var fileLocation = $('a[href="'+currentWindowLocation+'"]');
    $('a[href="'+currentWindowLocation+'"]').parents().map(function(){
        element.push(this);
        }
    ).get()

    $('a[href="'+currentWindowLocation+'"]').attr('href','#');
    var arrayLength = element.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        if(element[i].tagName == "UL" && element[i].className.match(/sub-menu/g) ){
            element[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
        }
        if(element[i].className.match(/has-children/g)){
            element[i].className = "has-children opened";
        }
    }


});
```

Other issue is with all browsers(Actually its not issue),

When try to click on any of parent menu >> opens sub-menu then redirects to relevant HREF,

**What I want is -** 
On click it should not open sub-menu at a first time, When it redirects to new page, it should open at that new page

Comment: Urgh... who must still support IE7 nowadays... Poor you! What's the jQuery version? jQuery 2.x is incompatible with old IE versions.

Comment: yea I know, But cant do anything beyond clients requirements !!

I'm using jquery-1.11.2

Comment: It seems this line element[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
isn't working on IE..its not adding display:block to sub-menu..and working on others

Comment: So try the pure JS way : `element[i].style.display = 'block'`.

Comment: yes it worked for me, But it was coincidence(Btwen your comment and my ans-deleted mine), You can post your answer :) I have another issue with this - when you try to click any of parent menu- it opens and redirects to relevant HREF, But I dont want to open it,it should just redirect..and then should open that menu at redirected page only

Comment: Try forcing `<a target="_self">` - http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y115y101y108y102y.html

Answer (score 0):

I got answer on of my offline friend

He said replace

```
element[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
```

with

```
element[i].style.display = "block";
```

and it worked

:)

Comment: Just when I post the exact same comment. Too bad for me, I had the solution!

Comment: yes, But it was coincidence, You can post your answer :) I have another issue with this - when you try to click any of parent menu- it opens and redirects to relevant HREF, But I dont want to open it,it should just redirect..and then should open that menu at redirected page only